# Why would an alien communicate with humans?

Tags: psychology

Inspired by a Joe Rogan podcast I started writing and drawing some things this morning and I wanna create a short scene where the classic movie thropes meets the hunter morale and mentality.

Classic scene where the big hero meets the big alien emperor sitting on his throne.

The hero is forced on his knees by guards in a spaceship. He's not struggling to escape, there's no escape and he knows it.

Communication between the aliens and humans never happened before hand, at least the aliens never responded, they just came in wrecking havoc and attacking everything at sight.

But in this scene the hero tries to speak with the alien simply asking "why?" with dying voice as he drops blood from his mouth and eyes.

The emperor puts a vocal mask that allows him to make different sounds (kind of like we have instruments) and replies in human voice by explaining that humans deserve this fate, this is mercy! Humans are wild creatures doomed by their own savage nature condemned to a life of suffering and dying of hunger, cold or war...the heavy hand of the emperor grabbing humanity by the neck and chocking her is nothing but a warm loving and pitiful kiss of mercy in this wild and cold universe.

I was wondering (it doesn't matter for the story, it's just something that bothers me), **why would a hunter use a device that allow them to speak with their prey?**

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. We solve worldbuilding problems, not plot problems. This sounds like a problem of your plot. As such it doesn't look a good fit here. More info in the [help]

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica I disagree. The OP states very clearly that this isn't about his story; he is asking why alien hunters *in general* would want to talk to their prey. That being said, I do see where you are coming from; the OP *does* provide much more information about his story than is strictly necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: entertainment.

Life on a world-destroying spaceship is boring. "Burning the land and boiling the seas" was cool and interesting at first, but you can only see so many nuclear explosions until you realise there are only three types of cities and it's just all way too predictable. So every once in a while you teleport one of the inhabitants onto your ship, make them watch the destruction of their city (or even planet?) and then drop them back into the ruins to die from exposure, hunger&thirst, radioactivity and what not. Sometimes you speak to them, to enjoy their helplessness and desperation, just because you are the almighty but bored devourer of worlds...

You can see plenty enough examples of "playing with the prey" in nature (and humans!), if nothing else the proverbial cat and mouse!

Answer (score 1):

### Extreme utilitarianism gone wild

Utilitarianism is a kind of morale theory that try to maximise the global happiness.
With the famous trolley problem, they wouldn't have any problem to kill one person to save the others.

Pushing this ethical theory to the extreme, killing one people, to take his organs and save 5 people would be the morale thing to do.

Your aliens are extreme utilitarianists. They dont kill humans because it's funny. They kill humans because it increase the global hapiness of the universe. And to minimize the human suffering, they even make their death painless, rather than war, cold or hunger.

And as what they do is morale from their point of view, there is no problem to explain it to humans